# Capitalization of the enterprise IT industry

Tags: capitalization

I often find myself in the situation of wanting to capitalize the phrase "Enterprise IT" due to its frequency of reference as the title of my industry. It feels appropriate when I write:

"In Enterprise IT ..."
"The Enterprise IT industry..."

I would not be surprised if my capitalization is off here. Could one of you help me with a definitive answer to the argument?

Comment: I couldn't find anything to "correct" in your grammar, so I knocked out ***thanks*** on the grounds that we generally discourage such superfluous "chatty" elements in question text here on ELU. (We can take it for granted you'll be grateful if you get a good answer! :)

Comment: Your capitalization seems correct to me (and would also work with Business IT).

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers. I'm used to the tough crowd of developers, but I anticipated a more cordial environment here. I won't make that mistake twice :)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch based on what rules of grammar?

Comment: @mjb capitalization of proper nouns.

Comment: @mjb: Please don't misunderstand me. I think the mods here on ELU are very tolerant of blatantly Off Topic *comments* (such as this one, which is obviously nothing to do with your question as such). I'm *not* a mod, but I'm in complete agreement with their general position that *questions* (and to a lesser extent, *answers*) should be more concise (and stick to the point! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the "right" answer, but no-one else has posted one, so...

---

The initialism ***IT*** has to be capitalised - but if it were spelt out in full, it normally wouldn't be...

> *OP works for a company specialising in **information technology**.*

In my opinion, OP's use of adjectival ***enterprise*** modifying ***IT*** smacks of "industry jargon", so bearing in mind [what they say here,](http://searchcio.techtarget.com/definition/enterprise-IT-enterprise-class-IT) I'd suggest sidestepping the issue by opting for...

> *OP works for a company specialising in **enterprise-class information technology**.*
>    ...which would commonly be shortened to...
>     *OP works for a company specialising in **enterprise-class IT**.*

---

I can't see any real justification for capitalising ***enterprise***. So if OP is happy to use it...

> *?OP works for a company specialising in **enterprise IT**.*

...is the only game in town. I'm no copy editor, obviously, but I don't think I could endorse...

> *∗OP works for a company specialising in **Enterprise IT**.*

Comment: The only reason that Certain People would capitalize the Word would be draw attention to its magnificent Self-Importance.

Comment: @tchrist: Good point. It's also worth noting that your text there has a somewhat quaint/archaic flavour, in that the practice was much more common centuries ago. Which arguably makes it even *less* appropriate for OP's specific case where the context is very definitely bang up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, large businesses have business units that include the word "Enterprise" in their title. In that case, when referring to a business unit by its proper name, it would correctly be capitalized. For example, "We're working with Enterprise IT" would be capitalized if it were a reference to a proper noun, but not if it were a reference to the general practice of enterprise information technology. Sometimes, business unit names are also shortened in practice, so the shortened name is a substitute for the complete proper name - for example if the business unit were named "Enterprise-Wide IT Systems and Services", it might be referred to as "Enterprise IT" or "Enterprise Systems", but I agree that it should not be normally capitalized in standard usage.